# JSON Serialization of pojos with child objects

Tags: java, json, serialization, jersey

Let's say I have a restful webservice with the following interfaces:

```
GET /some/parent
```

This will return something like

```
[
    {
        urn: "/some/parent/1",
        name: "parent1",
        children: [ "/some/child1", "/some/child2" ]
    },
    {
        urn: "/some/parent/2",
        name: "parent2",
        children: [ "/some/child3", "/some/child4" ]
    }
]
```

and, i've got

```
GET /some/parent/{id}
```

that return something like this:

```
{
    urn: /some/parent/1,
    name: parent1,
    children: [
        {
            urn: "/some/child1",
            name: "child1"
        },
        {
            urn: "/some/child2",
            name: "child2"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, when requesting a list of parents, the json representations for every parent will be list with the child urns. When requesting a specific parent resource the json representation will contain a list of child json representations.

With jersey the common way would be to define two simple java pojos and a simple Resource:

```
public class Parent {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<String> childIds;
    ...
    @JsonIgnore
    public String getId()...
    @JsonProperty
    public String getUrn()...
}

public class Child {
    private String id:
    private String name;
    ...
    @JsonIgnore
    public String getId()...
    @JsonProperty
    public String getUrn()...
}

@Path("/some/parent")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ParentResource() {
    @GET
    public List<Parent> findAll() {
        List<Parent> result = // some database query call
        return result;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    public Parent find(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        Parent parent = // some database call
        return parent;
    }
}
```

How can I inject the child urns/objects in the above scenarios? Are there any best practices? How do you solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would rather make an extended Parent class like this:

```
public class ParentExtended extends Parent {
    private List<Child> childrenObjects;

    public ParentExtended(Parent parent) {
        this.id = parent.getId();
        ...
    }

    @JsonProperty("children")
    public List<Child> getChildrenObjects() { ... }

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public List<String> getChildren() { ... }
}


@Path("/some/parent")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ParentResource() {
    @GET
    public List<Parent> findAll() {
        List<Parent> result = // some database query call
        return result;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    public ParentExtended find(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        Parent parent = // some database call
        ParentExtended parentEx = new ParentExtended(parent);

        for (String childId : parent.getChildren()) {
            parentEx.getChildrenObjects().add(// fetch the child object);
        }
        return parentEx;
    }
}
```

It is not a very nice way. I am open to other alternatives...

Answer (score 0):

You don't store the child ids in the parent object, you store a list of the children as objects...

```
public class Parent {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<Child> children;
    ...
    @JsonIgnore
    public String getId()...
    @JsonProperty
    public String getUrn()...
}
```

Comment: Ok, that's a solution but that gives me another problem. I store the parent object into a nosql database like couchdb. The children are separate objects and I don't want to fetch the child objects when requesting many parent objects.

Comment: Yeah, we have that issue as well. It's a question of whether or not you really need all of the child objects or if you just need the ids so the client can fetch the ones they need. We have both scenarios and sometimes we load "fat" objects with the children populated, other times we load "thin" objects with just their UIDs. There's really no silver bullet here.