# Deep JSON Serialization of JPA Entities

Tags: java, json, jpa, serialization, jersey

Using `jersey-json` POJO serialization feature on a jersey service function to return a JPA entity or a `List<?>` of that entity, how can I "tell" the serializer to dig deeper when serializing?

In other words, how do I tell the POJO Serializer to do a "Deep Serialization" (or specify the depth of each property) which returns a more detailed JSON with deeper data of the JPA object including it's mappings and relationships with other objects, those annotated with `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany`?

Without having to use that kind of solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10615608/230637
(My problem with the linked solution is the necessity to declare a bloated copy-constructor).

Thanks.